# PowerPivot relationship based on two columns per table

Tags: powerpivot

I have a table *geoLocations* which holds among others the two columns *latitude* and *longitude*. There is a second table (let's name it cities), which holds for each unique pair of *laitude* and *longitude* the corresponding city.

How can I model this relationship using PowerPivot? Creating two separate relationships will fail, as one coordinate may occur several times in the lookup-table (only the combination of both is unique).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7):

You should create a key in each table that concatenates the 2 fields together. This could be done in a calculate column eg:

= LATITUDE & "-" & LONGITUDE

Or on import which would yield better performance on a large data set.

Jacob